# USB C via hub to two laptops?

Tags: usb, usb-c

I have two laptops, one for work and one for home, and a Kensington SD4700P dock that work gave me. The dock only connects peripherals via the rear C port (the front C port seems to be solely a charger), so I still have to swap the C output between the two laptops depending which one is on.

I am looking for some sort of mini hub that would plug into the Dock's C port and then run into both laptops so that I can effectively not have to unplug anything at all but can't seem to find anything suitable - the hubs I've looked at (i.e. Belkin F4U090btBLK) seem to only connect to a single laptop so the concern is that I'd still be cable swapping.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: USB requires one host & multiple peripherals. To be able to support two hosts, you need to be looking at something more akin to a KVM.

Comment: A USB "Toggle" or "Switch" might bring up better search results. I've seen many USB 2.0 ones for sharing something like a printer between two devices. Newer USB-C devices are a lot more complex and probably don't work reliably through the kind of circuitry that would allow you to toggle all of those pins between two sources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [USB switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0967GXNGK) basically.  You still have to switch back and forth between laptops, but you do it via the click of a switch rather than swapping out cables.